# Add baseURL to homepage

Tags: php, url, redirect

I need to point my site's logo image (located in top left corner in main menu) to point to the homepage on click.

I use below php code which I've found from another question here, but it's not working as I expected. It redirects me to current page without pointing me to the homepage.

```
<?php echo "http://" . $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']; ?>
```

I'm on local development with XAMPP installed, php 7.2 and apache on wordpress

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your website is in the root, you could just add `/`.

If you want to full URL use:

```
<?php echo "http://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]"; ?>
```

Or if you want to support both HTTP and HTTPS, you can use:

```
<?php echo (isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) && $_SERVER['HTTPS'] === 'on' ? "https" : "http") . "://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]"; ?>
```

### Edit

Because you are in a subfolder you should also retrieve that foldername.

```
<?php echo (isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) && $_SERVER['HTTPS'] === 'on' ? "https" : "http") . "://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]/" . basename(dirname($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'])); ?>
```

I would add this to a function like so:

```
<?php 

function home_url() {
    $scheme = (isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) && $_SERVER['HTTPS'] === 'on' ? "https" : "http");
    $host = $_SERVER[HTTP_HOST];
    $folder = basename(dirname($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']));
    return "$scheme://$host/$folder";
}

echo home_url();
```

Comment: when I use **<?php echo "http://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]"; ?>** it redirects me to http://localhost  and second one do the same. why is that? my project location is htdocs/mysiter

Comment: That is because you are in a subfolder. I've edited my answer.

Comment: He is not in subfolder, he has to create project in htdocs to access project by name, example localhost/armin has path of "htdocs/armin/" 

It redirects you to localhost because you are on localhost, your computer is your host, your pc is local so that is localhost, and you do not need protocol you can take use 


<?php echo "//" . $_SERVER[HTTP_HOST] ; ?>


When you put // infront of link it checks if it i http or https and it takes propper protocol

Comment: @RonvanderHeijden **Edit** section of your answer did the job. I used the function in my wprdpress theme and it works fine now. I have another concern. Will this work everywhere? I mean if I change the peoject folder location, or put this into a web hosting server etc..?